# Laravel 4 optional route parameters

Tags: laravel-4, parameter-passing, laravel-routing

How to achive this route :

/test
/test/page-2

I want to pass "2" as parameter and if we are in page 1 just show /test not /test/page

Comment: Why not `/test/page/2`? you could simply do `/test/page/{page?}`.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with the above comment, why not just use the page number alone as a parameter?

**Routes:**

```
Route::get('test', ['uses' => 'TestController@index']);    
Route::get('test/page/{pageNumber?}', ['uses' => 'TestController@index']);
```

**TestController method:**
Assuming your views are in a directory `tests` and are named `testPage-1`, `testPage-2`, `testPage-3`, etc...

```
public function index($pageNumber = 1){
    return View::make('tests.testPage-'.$pageNumber);
}
```